# What does var this.mtx[i][lead] do in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was going through a reduced row echelon form code for javascript from this website: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Reduced_row_echelon_form#JavaScript and I was trying to put it into simpler code so that I could understand what each instruction did. I then ran into: while (this.mtx[i][lead] == 0). I understand what the this.mtx[i] is but I don't know what [lead] in the context of being right after mtx[i] does. Your helps is greatly appreciated. Here is the code:

```
Matrix.prototype.toReducedRowEchelonForm = function() {
var lead = 0;
for (var r = 0; r < this.rows(); r++) {
    if (this.columns() <= lead) {
        return;
    }
    var i = r;
    while (this.mtx[i][lead] == 0) {
        i++;
        if (this.rows() == i) {
            i = r;
            lead++;
            if (this.columns() == lead) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    var tmp = this.mtx[i];
    this.mtx[i] = this.mtx[r];
    this.mtx[r] = tmp;

    var val = this.mtx[r][lead];
    for (var j = 0; j < this.columns(); j++) {
        this.mtx[r][j] /= val;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < this.rows(); i++) {
        if (i == r) continue;
        val = this.mtx[i][lead];
        for (var j = 0; j < this.columns(); j++) {
            this.mtx[i][j] -= val * this.mtx[r][j];
        }
    }
    lead++;
}
return this;
}
```

Comment: its reading 2-d matrix, here 'lead is y axis'

Comment: So in the context of the while loop what does it mean? Does it mean while (this.mtx[i] == 0 && this.mtx[lead] ==0) or does it mean while(this.mtx[i] ==0 || this.mtx[lead] == 0)? Or is it something else?

Comment: suppose you have
var obj = {
obj1:{o:4},
obj2:3
}
and you want to access the value of x when you can do it using **obj.obj1.o** or **obj[obj1][o]**
Here the key has known so we can any of the two syntax But it key to be accessed is variable you can't use obj.obj1.o there you need to use the second syntax obj[obj1][o]

Comment: So I can understand this better the first value of this.mtx[i][lead] is the value of the first item in the matix because it is accessing the value of lead in the 2d array. So if we had 1,2,3 and another equation 5,3,5 the value of of this.mtx[i][lead] is equal to 1 the first time through.